# Rails - Devise, how can I disable some default routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I want to completely disable the routes /users/sign_in for get and post.

I was able to successfully override them using the following:

```
  devise_for :users do
      get "/admin" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
      post "/admin" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
  end
```

And when I run rake routes I see the following:

```
    new_user_session GET    /admin(.:format)                {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
    user_session     POST   /admin(.:format)                {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"create"}
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
                     POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

I can access the sign in from /admin as well as from /users/sign_in. But I want to completely remove the last two rows, is it possible?

I tried some different combinations from the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) which seems to do it but it also overrides some useful ones, like the password/new and password/edit routes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Katz's solution no longer works as noted by Cirulli.

Try the following.

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]

as :user do
    get "/admin" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
    post "/admin" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
end
```

Answer (score 23):

You can achieve this by using the :skip option to devise_for:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions] do
    get "/admin" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
    post "/admin" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
end
```

When I run rake routes after that, I get just:

```
    new_user_session GET    /admin(.:format)               {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
        user_session POST   /admin(.:format)               {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"create"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! I also added this       delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session for the logout and the functionality is exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. `devise_for` looks like it's ignoring the block.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions,:registrations], controllers: {
  omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

when you skip `sessions` controller, you most add `destroy` action to your custom routes too:

```
as :user do
    get "/admin" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
    post "/admin" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```