# Rails - Specify http verb PUT or DELETE from the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to specify a put or delete http verb from the route.rb, for a specific path?

Like:

`get 'photos/show'`

I tried to do it with match like the below:

```
match 'photos/show' => 'photos#show', :via => :delete
```

In the rake routes it seems right but it doesn't do a delete http request. Also I tried:

`match 'photos/show' => 'photos#show', :via => :random`

And in the rake routes its shows "random"

It seems that you can specify get or post as shown in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints), but I don't know if I can specify put or delete. Is it possible?

Comment: what's wrong with `put 'photos/:id(.:format)', :to => 'photos#update'` ?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't try PUT verb but I didn't find something on the routes.rb so I thought that it might not works as the DELETE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
put 'photos/:id(.:format)', :to => 'photos#update'
delete 'photos/:id(.:format)', :to => 'photos#destroy'
```

or

```
resources :photos
```

and hit your app directory with

```
rake routes
```

C'mon, you're not even trying!

Comment: Ok the problem is inside the devise scope then. I tried it inside:
devise_scope :user do
  delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
And it didn't work. Any suggestions for that?? Thank you.

Comment: And what for do you need that? If you want custom devise routes you can try `devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "signup", :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" }`

Comment: It seems you want some deeper customization. You may want to update your question then to lure the right person here.

Comment: I've tried that also. It adds "/users/logout" etc. I want it without the "users" prefix. I tried to ask something a little different because I asked => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418514/rails-devise-how-can-i-disable-some-default-routes and I didn't get any answers.

Comment: And how did you know this not working? `devise_scope :user do
    delete "logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end` and `<%= link_to "Sign out", '/logout', :method => :delete %>`. Works for me.

Comment: It doesn't work, it says "Unknown action Could not find devise mapping for path "/logout". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end ". Restart your server and you propably see it too. I am using rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.9.3 . I've tried many things, like changing the config.sign_out_via = :delete from the devise.rb but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing prevents you from using put/post/delete 'directly', in place of match.

As an example, this works for me:

```
get 'user/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_current_user
put 'signup' => 'users#update'
```

The via option is useful when you want to route like eg this (not a frequent case, though):

```
match 'user/show' => 'users#show', :via => [:get, :post]
```