# How do I limit Devise routes down to just new/destroy session & OmniAuth routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Devise / OmniAuth (with Facebook login), and I'm trying to limit Devise routes down to **just this**, because I want to only allow login via Facebook.

```
                  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) callbacks#:action
```

but instead, I can't seem to pare the set of routes down to anything less than this (without also blowing away `new_user_session` and `destroy_user_session`):

```
                  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) callbacks#:action
           user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT      /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                       registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)               registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                  registrations#edit
                         PATCH    /users(.:format)                       registrations#update
                         PUT      /users(.:format)                       registrations#update
                         DELETE   /users(.:format)                       registrations#destroy
```

A few other questions (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418514/rails-devise-how-can-i-disable-some-default-routes)) I've found indicate that `:skip` in `routes.rb` can help, e.g.:

`devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]`

The problem with that approach is that it blows away `new_user_session` and `destroy_user_session`. Basically, I want the user to be able to navigate to a sign in page (`new_user_session_path`) and sign out (via `destroy_user_session_path`).

I think I'm missing some fundamental concept here, but I'm not sure what it is. Essentially, I'd like to disable these routes:

- `devise/sessions#create` (why would I need it if login is always through Facebook)
- `devise/passwords#create`
- `devise/passwords#new`
- `devise/passwords#edit`
- `devise/passwords#update`
- `registrations#cancel`
- `registrations#create`
- `registrations#new`
- `registrations#edit`
- `registrations#update`
- `registrations#destroy`

How could I accomplish this? (or does what I'm trying to do even make sense?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418514/rails-devise-how-can-i-disable-some-default-routes not sure if this helps..

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/test/rails_app/config/routes.rb#L40 Check it out! Using only: [:registration]

Answer (score 4):

You can define individual routes by removing the `devise_for` call and using `devise_scope` like so:

```
# routes.rb

devise_scope :user do
  get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
  delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  # etc...
end
```

Then, you'll have granular control over the Devise routes.

Hope that helps.